# For loop in Django template not processing

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-2.0

I create a dictionary, and pass it to my Django template:

```
my_dict = {'boo': {'id':'42'}, 'hi': {'id':'42'}}
t = get_template('my_site.html')
html = t.render(my_dict)
print(html)
return HttpResponse(html)
```

My Django template looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
Out of Dictionary <div>
    {% for key in my_dict %}
    <span>{{ key }}</span>
    {% endfor %} 
</div>
After dictionary    
</body>
</html>
```

My output in the browser looks like this:
Out of Dictionary
After dictionary

The HTML looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
Out of Dictionary <div>

</div>
After dictionary
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried the following to get the dict to be recognized:

```
{% for key in my_dict %}
{% for key in my_dict.items %}
{% for key, value in my_dict.items %}
{% for (key, value) in my_dict.items %}
```

Comment: You didn't pass your dict to template

Comment: Where is `my_dict` used anywhere in your python code?

Comment: I changed some variables for posting...

Comment: I did pass the dict in my original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_dict = {'boo': {'id':'42'}, 'hi': {'id':'42'}}
t = get_template('my_site.html')
html = t.render(my_dict)
```

Your context has two keys, `boo` and `hi`. You can access them in the template as follows:

```
{{ boo }}, {{ hi }}
```

If you want to use `mydict` in the template, you would nest that dictionary in the context dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'boo': {'id':'42'}, 'hi': {'id':'42'}}
context = {'my_dict': my_dict}
t = get_template('my_site.html')
html = t.render(context)
```

In the template you can then do:

```
{{ my_dict }}
```

or

```
{% for key, value in mydict.items %}
  {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I put "print(self.nodelist)" in django.template.base.Template.init, and it printed the nodes it was expecting. That showed me your nesting of my_dict was right. 
I also put print(context) under django.template.backends.django.Template.render, and that showed me the context was formed.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a Context object and pass it in to the render function.  See this example from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context)

Secondly, for your code to work as I think you are intending.. you actually need to add another layer on top of what you have so you can reference `my_dict` in your template

```
t.render(Context({'my_dict': {'boo': {'id':'42'}, 'hi': {'id':'42'}}}))
```

Comment: I'm using Django 2.0.2.  After Django 1.11 you get the error "TypeError context must be a dict rather than Context." if you pass a Context to render.

Comment: In that case.. you should only need
    `t.render({'my_dict': {'boo': {'id':'42'}, 'hi': {'id':'42'}}})`